# How to know which port is used?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, localhost

I'm using a lot of docker containers including nginx, etc.

My API is available on configured hostname, e.g.:

api.local.awesome.com/api/

Is it possible to check somehow which port it's using?

This is needed to configure global access for this API via `<IP>:<port>` configuration.

It looks like I've got my `api.local.awesome.com` on 8001 port but it doesn't work via this:

`192.168.1.3:8001/api/` - this doesn't work at all.
`192.168.1.3:8001` - this works for root endpoint.

Btw, `api.local.awesome.com/api/` works fine.

I was also trying to use `ngrok` on port 8001 but it works in the same way as `192.168.1.3:8001`.

Any suggestions, how to know a correct port for this?

Comment: telnet, nmap,,,

Comment: GUI apps like [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) or [TCPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview). Here is [list of TCP and UDP ports](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Answer (score 0):

If you connect via HTTP without a port number in the URL, it's port 80.

If you connect via HTTPS without a port number in the URL, it's port 443.

Edited to add:
If you're serving multiple websites via multiple hostnames on the same IP address (sometimes called virtual hosting), you can't connect to the server by IP address, because your browser (or other user agent / HTTP client) won't know which domain name to supply in the HTTP request's "Host:" header, so the server won't know which domain name's website to serve you.